# Gradle SLF4J Redshift JDBC conflict

Tags: java, gradle, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I need to update the version of JDBC Redshift driver in gradle and it looks like 1.3X has the following problem:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazon.redshift/redshift-jdbc42/1.2.37.1061/daad21f8637b6ccd2b86307a4f17e1e215df7365/redshift-jdbc42-1.2.37.1061.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

I can exclude `ch.qos.logback/logback-classic` globally, but I'm wondering if there's a better way around that since I'd rather disable the unexpected duplicate logger from `com.amazon.redshift/redshift-jdbc42`

Comment: You should complain to Amazon: implementations of `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` don't belong in a JDBC driver implementation.

Comment: That definitely, but wondering if there's some sort of workaround I can go with before they start following conventions

Answer (score 0):

The sl4j dependency seems to have been added starting at version 1.2.34.1058. You can use any version below that without having the multiple SLF4J bindings.

I hope it helps. :)

Comment: Not quite because I need "PreparedStatement parameters in some multi-threaded environments are not correctly populated." bugfix from 1.2.32 and you can't use that in Gradle directly from what I saw. It's also not a dependency, if it was all would be good.